# problem when i install react-leaflet-search

Tags: reactjs, npm, leaflet, react-leaflet, react-leaflet-search

i have a problem when i try to install react-leaflet-search i had this error

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: map-leaflet@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR! react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.12.0" from react-leaflet-search@2.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-leaflet-search
npm ERR! react-leaflet-search@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\ramy\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\ramy\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-09-25T09_01_07_075Z-debug.log
```

and i dont want to change my react version !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `npm install react-leaflet-search --legacy-peer-deps`

Before NPM 7.0, NPM would notify you if peer dependencies were missing. Since NPM 7.0, if the peer dependency is missing, NPM will try to install it resulting in your conflict. `--legacy-peer-deps` flag makes NPM follow the pre 7.0 convention.

Comment: thanks bro it works, and sorry i couldn't up vote u i don't know why